# How to change the style of a row in a WPF DataGrid control when a property of the item in that row changes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I've got a `DataGrid` control in my WPF application that contains an object.  There is a boolean property of that object which can be changed by user actions.  I need the style of the row to change when that property's value changes.

I have written a class that descends from `StyleSelector`:

```
public class LiveModeSelector : StyleSelector {

    public Style LiveModeStyle { get; set; }
    public Style NormalStyle { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle( object item, DependencyObject container ) {
        DataGridRow gridRow = container as DataGridRow;
        LPRCamera camera = item as LPRCamera;
        if ( camera != null && camera.IsInLiveMode ) {
            return LiveModeStyle;
        }
        return NormalStyle;
    }
}
```

The View Model class in question implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and it raises the `PropertyChanged` event when the property in question changes.

```
// Note:  The ModuleMonitor class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and raises the PropertyChanged
// event in the SetAndNotify generic method.
public class LPRCamera : ModuleMonitor, ICloneable {

    . . .

    public bool IsInLiveMode {
        get { return iIsInLiveMode; }
        private set { SetAndNotify( "IsInLiveMode", ref iIsInLiveMode, value ); }
    }
    private bool iIsInLiveMode;

    . . .

    /// </summary>
    public void StartLiveMode() {
        IsInLiveMode = true;

         . . .
    }


    public void StopLiveMode() {
        IsInLiveMode = false;

        . . .
    }
}
```

The value of the property is changed when the user performs the required action, but the style doesn't change.

I have placed a breakpoint in the SelectStyle method  and I see the breakpoint gets hit when the control is first loaded, but it does not get hit when the property's value changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this that grew out of @Rachel's answer to my question.  However, the code details differ somewhat and I want to show exactly what works.

The first step was to combine the two different `Styles` into one for the `DataGridRow` class:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="CameraStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The second step was to set the `DataGrid` control's `RowStyle` property to this new style:

```
<DataGrid . . .
          RowStyle={StaticResource CameraStyle}">
          . . .
</DataGrid>
```

This works.  The foreground and background of the row changes when the user puts the `LPRCamera` associated with that row into Live Mode and changes back to normal when they take it out of Live Mode, which is what I was going for.

Thanks @Rachel!

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to suggest this based on your comment, but I see you've already figured this out for yourself so +1 :)

Comment: There's an interesting little twist to this problem.  It turns out that when I first tried this, the colors of only the first column in the first row changed.  If you put a camera in any other row into Live Mode, the colors didn't change.  It turns out that I had a style for the `DataGridCell` class in my app.xaml and I was changing the colors of the `DataGridRow` class.  I changed the style in app.xaml so it applied to the `DataGridRow` class and everything worked.  So the lesson is to make sure you always manipulate the styles of the same class, preferably the the `DataGridRow` class!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a `StyleSelector` listens for `PropertyChange` notifications, so it doesn't get re-run when the `IsInLiveMode` property gets changed.

Put your style in a `DataTrigger` based on `IsInLiveMode` instead, and it will get re-evaluated anytime the property change notification gets raised.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="Style1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="Style2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource Style1}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=DataContext.IsInLiveMode}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource Style2}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  There's only one problem:  The `DataGrid` is populated by binding the `ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` of `LPRCamera` objects.  The collection is not stored in the `DataContext` of anything.  How do I get the `DataTrigger` to bind to the particular `LPRCamera` object in the specific row of the `DataGrid` it is referenced by?